# vsftpd upload file error

Tags: centos, permissions, ftp

I am setting up a vsftpd server (in centos) which allows anonymous READ/WRITE.Here is my configuration

```
anonymous_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
anon_upload_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_file=/var/log/xferlog
xferlog_std_format=YES
ftpd_banner=Welcome to blah FTP service.
listen=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=NO
tcp_wrappers=YES
anon_root=/var/ftp/
```

In my `/var/ftp/` folder. The permission is set to 777 which is owned by root.
When i tried `put /file/path/here.txt` I am getting 553 error. Are there any setting that i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

SELinux context must be `public_content_rw_t`, set it with `chcon -t public_content_rw_t /var/ftp`